# AFNetworking Upload Using NSMutableURLRequest?

Tags: php, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to learn `AFNetworking`, and I've taken a sample from their Github. I don't know what parameters to set in `dataToPost`using the the `php` I have. I'm new to `Objective-C` and `php`. Can someone take a look at my snippet and my `php` to see what I'm missing. It's hard to find "upload" tutorials for `AFNetworking`, but there are TONS of `JSON` tutorials out there.

I want to use a `NSMutableURLRequest` because eventually I would like to upload from an array or `UITableview`; here is mt code so far:

PHP:

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$uploaddir = './';      //Uploading to same directory as PHP file
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadFile = $file;
$randomNumber = rand(0, 99999); 
$newName = $uploadDir . $randomNumber . $uploadFile;


if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) { 
     $result = array("success" => false);  
      echo json_encode($result);  
      exit();
}

if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']> 300000) {
    $result = array("success" => false, "message" =>"the uploaded file is too big");  
          echo json_encode($result);  
          exit(); 
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
    $postsize = ini_get('post_max_size');   //Not necessary, I was using these
    $canupload = ini_get('file_uploads');    //server variables to see what was 
    $tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');   //going wrong.
    $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    //echo "http://localhost:8888/upload/{$file}" . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] ;
    $result = array("success"   => true,
                "code"      => 0,
                "message"   => "success",
                "postsize"  => $postsize,
                "canupload" => $canupload,
                "tempdir"   => $tempdir,
                "maxsize"   => $maxsize);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

Xcode:

```
// 1. Create AFHTTPRequestSerializer which will create your request.
AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

// 2. Create an NSMutableURLRequest.
NSMutableURLRequest *request =
[serializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://my.com/upload/upload.php"
                                parameters:nil
                 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                     [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                                 name:@"userfile"
                                             fileName:@"myimage.jpg"
                                             mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                 }];

// 3. Create and use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to create an AFHTTPRequestOperation from the NSMutableURLRequest that we just created.
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
[manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                     NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
                                 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                     NSLog(@"Failure %@", error.description);
                                 }];

// 4. Set the progress block of the operation.
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger __unused bytesWritten,
                                    NSInteger totalBytesWritten,
                                    NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Wrote %ld/%ld", (long)totalBytesWritten, (long)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];

// 5. Begin!
[operation start];
```

ERROR (**resolved**):

```
2014-03-31 15:37:46.921 TestingUpload[7190:60b] Wrote 32768/59063
2014-03-31 15:37:46.922 TestingUpload[7190:60b] Wrote 59063/59063
2014-03-31 15:37:46.923 TestingUpload[7190:60b] Wrote 32768/59063
2014-03-31 15:37:46.923 TestingUpload[7190:60b] Wrote 59063/59063
2014-03-31 15:37:46.925 TestingUpload[7190:60b]     Success {
    canupload = 1;
    code = 0;
    maxsize = 32M;
    message = success;
    postsize = 32M;
    success = 1;
    tempdir = "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php";
}
2014-03-31 15:37:46.927 TestingUpload[7190:60b]     Success {
    canupload = 1;
    code = 0;
    maxsize = 32M;
    message = success;
    postsize = 32M;
    success = 1;
    tempdir = "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php";
}
```

Thanks for any help and explanation. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't tested it, but with a casual glance, that PHP looks pretty good.

Comment: check above. I don't care about to too big any longer because it is always going to be ~same size from the device.

Comment: The too big check is important if you want to be careful about some nefarious user noticing the URL for file uploading and deciding to upload a 2 gb file onto your server. That's why it's generally there; to minimize the chance of abuse by some miscreant. Not a big deal in your testing, but before you go to production, consider adding that code back in (but with JSON response).

Comment: yes works well...i added a for loop to see if i can upload 2+ images and it worked well. What were you saying about the file size?

Comment: @Rob Updated the PHP to what I interpreted you meant by JSON/size error. How does that look?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm suggesting. You might want to add the numerical `code` to your two error conditions, so the app can differentiate between them (you don't want to rely upon the string error message alone), but that's icing on the cake.

Comment: @Rob sweet thank you. Thanks for all your help! Do you know if I can dynamically make a folder on the server using php, if I pass a string for a folder name?

Comment: See [mkdir function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP is looking for the field name `userfile`, but your Objective-C is using `attachment`. You must use the same field name on both platforms. I also assume the "`<$php`" was just a typo and that you intended "`<?php`".

A couple of other improvements you might want to consider:

1. I would suggest that you might want to change your PHP to return JSON rather than just writing text strings. It will be easier for your Objective-C code to parse the responses and differentiate between various errors and success.

   For example, your if successful, your PHP might do the following:

   ```
   $result = array("success" => true, "code" => 0, "message" => "success");
   ```

   Or if you wanted to log those additional values, as in your existing code sample, you could:

   ```
   $result = array("success"   => true,
                   "code"      => 0,
                   "message"   => "success",
                   "postsize"  => $postsize,
                   "canupload" => $canupload,
                   "tempdir"   => $tempdir,
                   "maxsize"   => $maxsize);
   ```

   If unsuccessful, you might do:

   ```
   $result = array("success" => false, "code" => 1, "message" => "file not found");
   ```

   or

   ```
   $result = array("success" => false, "code" => 2, "message" => "file too large");
   ```

   Regardless of which `$result` is chosen, when done, you should JSON encode it and `echo` it (rather than echoing the simple text string):

   ```
   echo json_encode($result);
   ```

   Clearly, use whatever codes and messages you want, but the idea is to return JSON, which can be easily parsed to determine if the upload request was successful, and if not, then why. Trying to parse simple text responses from the server will be inherently fragile.

   Anyway, your Objective-C can then parse this response and just check the `success` or `code` values and handle these scenarios appropriately.
2. I would not suggest having the PHP save the uploads in the same folder as the PHP, itself. At the very least, I'd create a dedicated subdirectory for the uploads. I'd personally choose a directory completely outside the web server's directory structure.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. What do I pass in `parameters:dataToPost`? The <$php was a typo; I was having a hard time getting it to show as a code block. as far as the path to the uploads folder, I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible to understand the basic concept. For some reason I'm having a really hard time with this library. Can you repost your suggestions as changes to my php above - sorry I'm very new, although I do understand that the Obj-c is looking for an object in the response. Thanks again. Any clarifications on the obj-c above?

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about using `nil`, but didn't want to jump to conclusions. Are parameters used if I was querying MYSQL and needed a "username" and "password" in the URL? And I need to change `attachment` to `userFile`? what about the `fileName` in the `formdata`does that matter? its just a placeholder right?

Comment: Xcode says that `multipartFormRequestWithMethod` is depreciated?

Comment: I edited my question with the error and the fixed code.

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of your updated code sample and reported warnings/errors, I have a few observations:

1. You are receiving the message about `multipartFormRequestWithMethod` being deprecated because you're using the rendition without the `error` parameter, but that's been replaced with another rendition with this additional parameter. See the declaration of this method in `AFURLRequestSerialization.h` for more information.
2. Your error about the `text/html` is a result of the fact that PHP is sending a response with a header that reports a `Content-type` of `text/html`. If your PHP script is not sending JSON back in your PHP, you have to change your your Objective-C code so it knows to expect an HTTP response (by default, it expects JSON back):

   ```
   manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
   ```

   That tells the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` to accept any HTTP response back from the server.

   Alternatively, if you change your PHP to return JSON (and you should, IMHO), you need to not only change the PHP code to `echo` the `json_encode` of the results, but also inform PHP to specify the appropriate `Content-Type` in the header. So before you `echo` any JSON in your PHP), add the following line to the PHP code:

   ```
   header("Content-Type: application/json");
   ```
3. You said:

   > I thought the content type was defined in `mimetype`

   The `mimetype` defines the `Content-type` for that part of the multipart request. But the whole request has its own `Content-type` header, too. The response also bears a `Content-type` setting in its header. This error, is telling you that the response bore a `Content-type` of `text/html`, and it expected `application/json`. (See my prior point regarding fixing that.)

Comment: ok thanks. I'll look into `AFURLRequestSerialization.h` meanwhile, updated the PHP in my answer.